# Android RecyclerView which is in a Fragment which is in a ViewPager does not reload/refresh views if setOffscreenPageLimit is reached

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in a `Fragment` which again is in a `ViewPager`, when I swipe between `ViewPager` pages, I see that `onDetach` of `Fragment` is being called but for some reason `RecyclerView` is still present in that particular position for the `Fragment` in `ViewPager`, even the scroll position of `RecyclerView` is being preserved when I come back to the detached Fragment.

I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for `ViewPager` and I am returning `POSITION_NONE` from `getItemPosition()` but it has no effect.

Please help me understand the problem here.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but my guess is that FragmentManager has some caching functionality. subscribed.

Comment: How many pages do you have in your viewpager?

Comment: Its an infinite scrolling ViewPager with load more functionality.

Comment: Could you, please, post your adapter's code?

Comment: Adapters cache your fragments. you will have to remove everything state based inside your fragment or at least reset it, once its detached.

Comment: This can be easily reproduced as follows, create a Fragment with a RecyclerView as a child, create an Activity with a ViewPager with its Adapter extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter and add upto 10 Fragments in it, set setOffScreenPageLimit to 2, now scroll down/up on any RecyclerView and swipe 2 pages in ViewPager, now navigate back to the Fragment where RecyclerView was scrolled down/up; you will find that RecyclerView has retained its position even though onDetach had been called on that Fragment when you swiped 2 positions in ViewPager .

Comment: try to set setOffscreenPageLimit to nunber of pages

Comment: Don't try to increase page limit, it will reduce perf. If you want to reset RecyclerView, you can try to setAdapter(null) on fragment view destroy

Answer (score 1):

Try this points.

1) `MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

2) Set Adapter from fragment using `getChildFragmentManager()` 
eg : `mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getActivity(), this))`

3) From ViewpagerFrgment `Override` `setUserVisibleHint` method

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            //Update Recyclerview
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not a correct answer, you should have ready to use data in your fragment, not start loading when it is visible to user.

Answer (score 0):

it's because viewpager use a caching mecanism.
read this article :

http://doublenegative.com/fragment-state-restoration-and-the-fragmentstatepageradapter/

Answer (score 0):

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` saves the state and destroy the fragments; it also restores the state when fragments are recreated which restores the state of recycleview (the scrolling position).

From the end user it is the same behavior as using `FragmentPageAdapter` which keeps fragments in memory.

It's the normal and usually desired behavior.